# How to output the loss gradient backpropagation path through a PyTorch computational graph

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, loss-function, autograd

I have implemented a new loss function in PyTorch.

```
#model_1 needs to be trained
outputs = model_1(input)
loss = myloss(outputs,labels)

#output is how much to resize an image
#label give the image file index
#Below I am explaining myloss() function
org_file_name = pic_ + str(labels[0]) + ".png"
new_image = compress(org_image,outputs)
accuracy_loss = run_pretrained_yolov3(org_image, new_image)

#next two lines are modifying the same DAG
prev_loss = torch.mean((outputs-labels)**2)
new_loss = (accuracy_loss/prev_loss.item())*prev_loss
new_loss.backward()
```

Can anyone plz help me suggesting **how can I know regarding how the loss gradient backpropagation through the computational graph?**

[i.e., Actually, inside the myloss() function, I used some other pre-trained model applied in testing mode to get the difference or final loss value.] Now I want to know whether my new_loss.grad backpropagated through model1 or first through yolov3 then through model1? pretrained yolov3 is used on testing mode only.

I have tried tensorboard, it's not providing me that option. Any suggestions will be highly helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you try rephrasing?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to check? May be with some code?

Comment: I have added more codes to clarify the issue. Plz give me any possible suggestions regarding the loss gradient backpropagation